# C++/JavaScript Unity3D with Java

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to learn unity3D but am like getting to a Java Pro but i wanted to get into 3D game development and a checked out Unity3D and I found out it can be written using C++ or C# or JavaScript but since it can be written in JavaScript, can it also be written in Java or C?

Comment: Wow. This is a messy post; it's hard to tell what you're even asking. 

Short answer: No, you cannot use C or Java in Unity 3D. You can, however, use C# or Javascript, or their own custom scripting language, Boo.

Comment: And their JavaScript is not really JavaScript. It is UnityScript, which is somewhat different. See http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript for more information. C++ cannot be used inside Unity. If you have a pro version you can develop plugins in C++ and interface those with Unity, but as far as languages go, they rely on Mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is different to Java. A nice analogy that I have heard before is: "Java is to Javascript, what a car is to carpet".

Therefore, no you cannot use `Unity3D` in Java. However, here is a post that you can look at: [Best 3D Java Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197791/best-3d-java-engine).

Answer (score 0):

I used to be a Java programmer as well when I was first introduced to Unity3d and did not know anything about C# or especially Javascript. But I later found out how easy it was to pick up C#. Both are object oriented languages and very very similar in many ways (syntax is quite similar as well). In fact, if you are good at Java, you will have no problem taking on C# without problems. To precisely answer your question, no Unity does not allow coding in Java or C++